# ASP.NET CalendarExtender with Year view alone

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendarextender

I'm using ASP.NET AJAX calendar extender inside my asp.net gridview. Is it possible to customize it to display only Year since the Day and Month values are not needed for my case.

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalExtStartYear" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtStartYear"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try setting the `Format` property to the value:

```
yyyy
```

I would highly recommend not to use it if you only need the year value
as it will add extra load (that you dont really need)

You can put a combo box instead, load its values on page load event for minimum
and maximum year

Comment: Format work with the return value only, but calendar will display Day/Month/Year selection :(

Comment: still the Calendar will display Month and Day selection after Year selection

Comment: here is a jquery based solution for month, u can modify it to apply year only:
http://www.adilmughal.com/2009/12/real-world-scenario-month-based.html

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have tested this solution and it works fine:
add an event in the mark up OnClientShown="OnShown" so the extender markup will be:

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalExtStartYear" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtStartYear" OnClientShown="OnShown"/>
```

now add a java script function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

    function OnShown(sender, args )
    {

        sender._switchMode("years", true);  
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Usman, thanks for the reply, but still the Calendar will display Month and Day selection after Year selection.